# I'm caching a file. Is there a risk of temporary unavailability?

Tags: php

My site uses some complex queries and calculations, and to prevent the site from slowing down I'm looking into caching. I inted to create a script that runs every 30 minutes using a cronjob, which saves the html into a cache file. I am using:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('cache.html', 'w+');
fwrite($file, $html);
fclose($file);
?>
```

In the live page of the website, I include this cache.html file.

My question: what if someone loads the site exactly at the moment the cronjob script is trying to update the file. Is there a risk that the file is then empty or non-existent for a few seconds, triggering an error by the user?

Comment: Use memcache or redis

Comment: You can always use [`flock()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) to lock the file.

Comment: Thanks Phantom & Fred. Does that mean this risk does indeed exist? If not I rather keep it simple without large external libraries, it's just a simple website, Memcache seems a bit of an overkill, it's just one page...

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it could happen.

Comment: Yes, there is a race condition here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `fopen` call you use `w+` options which truncates the file.

IMO, if your other page reads the file at that moment, it will probably include an empty file. The file should still be there, though. Even if the file was missing, when the `include` fails, it will return false and issue an E_WARNING) as written in the documentation.

So to your question:

- The file will be empty for some time
- `include` doesn't trigger an error if the file doesn't exist, but returns false and issues an E_WARNING

The file will be empty until the `fwrite` appends the new content and this operation should also be atomic (under some conditions):

> If handle was fopen()ed in append mode, fwrite()s are atomic (unless the size of string exceeds the filesystem's block size, on some platforms, and as long as the file is on a local filesystem). That is, there is no need to flock() a resource before calling fwrite(); all of the data will be written without interruption.
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php